# A simple image-processing task with OpenCV in Unity3D

Tags: c#, opencv, unity-game-engine, texture2d

After importing an `OpenCV` plug-in for `Unity3D`, I wrote the following simple program.

As I was not sure where I should put the **source texture2d image** (*where do I put this, so Unity3D reads it by default?*) I made it public and dragged the **png file** with **842**x**296** dimensions onto the field in the `Unity Inspector`.

However, I get the "**UnityException: LoadRawTextureData: not enough data provided**" error message that points to the second `Util` (the code for the culprit line is at the bottom of this post) but I have no clue what is wrong? Could someone please help me understand it?

```
public class Main : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Texture2D _sourceTexture2D;
    Texture2D _resultTexture2D;

    void Start()
    {
        Texture2D _sourceTexture2D = new Texture2D(842, 296);
        Texture2D _resultTexture2D = new Texture2D(842, 296);

        Size size = new Size(842, 296);
                                            // 0 is type!
        Mat source = new Mat(size, 0);
        Mat result = new Mat(size, 0);

        Utils.fastTexture2DToMat(_sourceTexture2D, source);

        Imgproc.Canny(source, result, 0.5, 10);

        Utils.fastMatToTexture2D(result, _resultTexture2D);

        _resultTexture2D.Apply();
    }
}
```

This is where the error leads to (the line beginning with texture2D.LoadRawTextureData):

```
public static void fastMatToTexture2D(Mat mat, Texture2D texture2D)
{
        if (mat != null)
            mat.ThrowIfDisposed ();

        if (mat == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException ("mat");

        if (texture2D == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException ("texture2D");

        if (mat.cols() != texture2D.width || mat.rows() != texture2D.height)
            throw new ArgumentException("The output Texture2D object has to be of the same size!");

        #if UNITY_PRO_LICENSE || ((UNITY_ANDROID || UNITY_IOS || UNITY_WEBGL) && !UNITY_EDITOR) || UNITY_5 || UNITY_5_3_OR_NEWER

        #if UNITY_5 && !UNITY_5_0 && !UNITY_5_1 && !UNITY_5_2
        if (!mat.isContinuous ()) {
            throw new ArgumentException ("mat.isContinuous() must be true.");
        }

        Core.flip(mat, mat, 0);
        texture2D.LoadRawTextureData( (IntPtr)mat.dataAddr(), (int)mat.total() * (int)mat.elemSize() );
        texture2D.Apply();
        Core.flip(mat, mat, 0);

        return;
        #else
        return;
        #endif

        #else
        return;
        #endif
}
```

Comment: @joreldraw I do not understand what you mean. Are you asking to see some code or something?

Comment: Yes, Utils.fastTexture2DToMat , Utils.fastMatToTexture2D & Imgproc.Canny

Comment: why Mat type 0?

Comment: what's the texture data type of Unity? RGBA?

Comment: @Micka Thanks for your reply. I do not know the type. How do I find out the type of a png image? I was told if you do not know, just put zero. Is this not right?

Comment: typically CV_8U should be ok. But what number of channels does Unity expect?;Canny should deliver a 8UC1 but I guess Unity either expects RGB or RGBA, so try cvtColor(result, result, GRAY2BGRA and GRAY2_BGR.

Comment: @Micka Hi Micka, If a `Unity3D` app is developed using `C#`, is it possible to perform an Image Processing task using `.NET` functions? Are there any such methods in `C#` that would, for example, do image `binarization` or `segmentation`? I am trying to **avoid** importing/integrating **OpenCV** into my app, but I do need to do some image processing before I pass on a captured `Rect` image for character recognition, so I wonder if any `C#` code **after taking a screenshot in Unity3D** would help?